# MKDirectionResponse response always returns nil

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am trying to get route information between two points, however the MKDirectionResponse always prints nil on the console. I think I am missing something obvious. I looked for similar problems on stack but no avail.

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import UIKit

class GetDirections: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    var userLatitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
    var userLongitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        var destinationCoordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D
        =CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.9532293,-75.194119);

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 30        
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.userLatitude = 40.759211
        self.userLongitude = -73.984638
        var userLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D =        
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.userLatitude, self.userLongitude)
        var sourcePlacemark:MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: userLocation,              addressDictionary: nil)
        var destinationPlacemark:MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
        var source:MKMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        var destination:MKMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
        var directionRequest:MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

        directionRequest.setSource(source)
        directionRequest.setDestination(destination)
        directionRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile
        directionRequest.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

        var directions:MKDirections = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler({
            (response: MKDirectionsResponse!, error: NSError?) in
            if error != nil{
                println("Error")
            }
            if response != nil{
                println(response.description)
            }
            else{
                println("No response")
            }
            println(error?.description)
        })


        println("ok \(userLatitude), \(userLongitude)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]){
        if locations != nil{
            var currentLocation:CLLocation = locations.last as CLLocation
            userLatitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
            userLongitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
            println("ok \(userLatitude), \(userLongitude)")
        }
        else{
            println("Location object is nil")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError){
        println("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: That code seems to be working.  Are you sure the `nil` you see isn't for the `error` object (which means there's no error)?  Code is doing `println(error?.description)` after `println(response.description)`.

Comment: Instead of just `println(response.description)`, try `println("number of routes = \(response.routes.count)")` and `for r in response.routes { println("route = \(r)") }`.  For the coordinates you're using, I get 3 routes.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. I was thinking that it has to do with `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`. If it isn't **stopped** it keeps updating the location?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add MKMapView Delegate to your class and implement the

```
mapView(:MKMapView, rendererForOverlay : MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
```

delegate method to specify your overlay render (how your route will look on the map).